# OpenGL debugger / error tracer for OS X 10.7 (Lion)?

Tags: macos, opengl

What tool can I use best for tracing OpenGL errors? I once used gDEBugger, but that is not yet available for 10.7, and I used to have some problems with it. Xcode Instruments does seem to only have some driver statistics. All I need is a tracer that tells me which OpenGL call led to an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the OpenGL Profiler provided along with the development tools:

/Developer/Applications/Graphics Tools/OpenGL Profiler

This will let you attach to an application, dump a trace, or break when OpenGL encounters an error.

Comment: Ah! There it was hiding! I remember seeing it in XCode 3.x, but could not find it in XCode 4. I will try it!

Comment: This is a great tool and worked fine the first time I tried it - ever since though it hangs when doing almost anything...

Answer (score 1):

Try Xcode's Capture OpenGL ES Frame (in the Product->Debug menu). I haven't used it much, but it should be able to tell you when you are in error.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but my application is not OpenGL, plus it was not built using XCode (C++ Qt application).

Comment: was trying to write: "is not OpenGL ES, but standard OpenGL 2.1"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe glslDevil will help you. I know it is able to trace all OpenGl calls.

http://cumbia.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/glsldevil/

I don't know if it works under OSX.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I used glsldevil some time ago under Linux. However, OS X does not seem to be supported.